# Issues when trying to open an xlsx restricted file: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a big issue on a Java tool I work with.
Every time I try to upload an xlsx file that is marked as "Restricted with protection", I got the same exception

```
       **org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Can't open the 
                                 specified file: 'C:/bea/test.xslx'**

       **at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:106)**

       **at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:221)**



       **Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file**

      **at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.openZipFile(ZipHelper.java:174)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:104)
        ... 6 more**
```

There is no password on that excel file, it's just an upgrade of MS office that apply this kind of restriction for every file that is downloaded from the Internet. If I change it into "Unlimited access" everything is fine.

The java tool first create a copy of the excel file I try to upload in a temporary path. The file is correctly created (as the original one) into *excelPath*.
The exception is caught at this line

```
                      opcPkg = OPCPackage.open(excelPath, PackageAccess.READ);
```

I tried to change the PackageAccess into READ_WRITE, but nothing has changed.
The tool I'm working with is Java 8 based, it's built with Ant and runs on Jboss EAP 7.2.

--EDIT--
Thanks to @Markus and @Gagravarr I found there is a sort of encryption on that file that allows only selected people to open the document (ie. trying to open it in my personal laptop I'm asked to insert email and password to open it).
In order to repeat the exception it's suffice to open an xlsx, then go to File-->Info-->Protect Workbook -->Restrict Access  and change into "Restricted Access" as shown below

### [Restriction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0eoA.png)

Is anyone familiar with this kind of issue? Is it possible to bypass this kind of restriction and open the document in java?
Any hint would be really appreciated!
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: On which OS does your Java run? Which version of POI do you use? Please share the access rights of both input files, the one that works and the one that doesn't.

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-a-file-that-has-restricted-permissions-c7a70797-6b1e-493f-acf7-92a39b85e30c)? Something else? Whatever it is, if the file is protected, why are you surprised if POI fails to open it?

Comment: @Markus unix OS. POI version is 5.2.2. Good and bad files have the same read/write permission.

Comment: @Oliver,  it's a permission policy that Office automatically add to downloaded files. We would like to avoid asking users to first remove this permission and then uploading it.

Comment: Download the Apache Tika app jar, run that with `--detect` on the troublesome file, and report what Tika thinks the file that can't be opened with Apache POI is?

Comment: @Gagravarr  here is first part of The full exception stack trace:
org.apache.tika.exception.EncryptedDocumentException: DRM encrypted document is not yet supported by Apache POI
 at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:277)
 at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:175)
 at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:298)
 at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:298)
 at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:175)

Comment: Trying to open the file in my personal laptop I'm asked to insert email and password. I was not able to see this kind of protection since I was working on my business computer.

Comment: That exception give you your answer - Apache POI has no support for the kind of encryption your document is using

Comment: So you want to hack DRM encryption? Why should you want to? The user will have set this intentionally.

Comment: @Markus not at all! Users said that this kind of restriction policy was automatically applied on downloaded files. Anyway I will just suggest to change restriction before uploading files on the tool. thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between `ZipFile` and `ZipInputStream` implementation. Please try:

```java
File file = new File(excelPath);
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
opcPkg = OPCPackage.open(input);
```

**Update:**

[IRM restricted documents](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restrict-access-to-documents-with-information-rights-management-in-word-94aa8ab1-465e-42d7-a323-d61f911b2d0f) / [AD RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory_Rights_Management_Services) of course can not be opened by Apache POI. This is a microsoft specific feature that needs access to licensing server / Active Directory. I never heard of any implementation that integrates this on linux.

Comment: Thanks Markus for your answer! Changing code as you suggested brings the following InvalidFormatException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]

  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:178)
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:662)
  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:269)

Comment: @eleguitar Until now I can't reproduce the error in my environment. Can you share an example document (original and uploaded version) or can you think of a reproducible way to create such document? Because if I simply copy an `xlsx` that definitely is marked with "protected view" from windows to linux and try to open it with `OPCPackage`, I don't have this issue. Can you please binary compare the two documents (original and uploaded) in order to rule out that the file gets currupted on upload? Or can you copy the same file w/o upload-mechanism and check if it can be opened?

Comment: In order to repeat the exception it's suffice to open an xlsx, then go to File-->Info-->Protect Workbook -->Restrict Access  and change into "Restricted Access"